# oracle pl/sql how to call back this alias created for a parameter?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oraclereports

i have a query im doing to display records to oracle reports. the parameter i need as selection is the `class_code` but when user click on the dropdown value it's a bit messy for them(hard to explain here) so they ask to combine the `study_intake` and `class_code` as a word which would be clear to them.

now what i did is use AS for alias of a new column which combines the two, but i cant call it back (since it's not the right syntax)

here's a sample of my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT STUDENT_ATTENDENTS.IC_PASSPORT, 
STUDENT_ATTENDENTS.NAME,
 STUDENT_ATTENDENTS.A_DATE, 
STUDENT_ATTENDENTS.A_TYPE, 
STUDENT_ATTENDENTS.ATTEN, 
TUTORIAL_CLASSES_MASTER.LECTURER_NAME, 
STUDENT_ATTENDENTS.COURSE_CODE, 
STUDENT_ATTENDENTS.SUBJECT_CODE, 
SUBJECT_MASTER_TABLE.CREDIT_POINT,
TUTORIAL_CLASSES_MASTER.STUDY_INTAKE || ' ' || STUDENT_ATTENDENTS.CLASS_CODE AS Study_Intake_Class_Code


FROM STUDENT_ATTENDENTS, TUTORIAL_CLASSES_MASTER, SUBJECT_MASTER_TABLE

WHERE Study_Intake_Class_Code = :CLASS_DODE
AND STUDENT_ATTENDENTS.SUBJECT_CODE = SUBJECT_MASTER_TABLE.SUBJECT_CODE
AND (STUDENT_ATTENDENTS.CLASS_CODE = TUTORIAL_CLASSES_MASTER.CLASS_CODE)
```

the line `WHERE Study_Intake_Class_Code = :CLASS_DODE` will return an error which is

> ORA-00904: "STUDY_INTAKE_CLASS_CODE": invalid identifier

i cant use back the alias. an idea i came up with is to create a **view** but this made the report haywire and affecting all the formulas(i didnt create the original report)

how do i adjust this query to make it work? any ideas or other style of query?

Comment: You should also go back and accept some answers, may make people more willing to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the original query part into there where instead of the alias name... i.e.,

```
WHERE TUTORIAL_CLASSES_MASTER.STUDY_INTAKE || ' ' || STUDENT_ATTENDENTS.CLASS_CODE = :CLASS_DODE
```